# Can you force Facebook to recognize correct image without og: tags?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, meta-tags

I have a website where news articles get posted through CMS  and there is no option to add Facebook META OG tags to `<head>`. I could only add them manually to `<body>` but that won't work I assume?

Is there another solution where you can tell Facebook which image should be picked when using like/share buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This depends how you make the share. You can use the FB.Ui to request a "Post to a wall" where you can specify the specifics of what appears on the share.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

If you are sharing the URL only it will read your meta tags as you state. I have not tried making that image the first within the HTML as this may also make that the default.

you can use this link to debug your meta tags and test your sharing if you are sharing a URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: The debugger doesn't work properly imo. I have fixed my website (www.puresoftware.nl) and still it gives errors and won't rescrape my website. It says there is an 301 error, but when I debug my website it returns 200 OK, so where is the 301?

Comment: @asc2030 Do you have a working example of this perhaps ?